# Combine two sets of folders into new structure

Tags: batch, combine

I have two sets of folders, which are two versions of the same data with identical subfolders (200+). I need to combine the sets using a batch into a slightly new structure. For instance:

```
setA\folder1\A_files  
    \folder2\A_files  
    \folder3\A_files
```

```
setB\folder1\B_files  
    \folder2\B_files  
    \folder3\B_files
```

I need to setup setA like so:

```
setA\folder1\A_files_folder\A_files  
            \B_files_folder\B_files  
            \A_files  
    \folder2\A_files_folder\A_files  
            \B_files_folder\B_files  
            \A_files  
    \folder3\A_files_folder\A_files  
            \B_files_folder\B_files  
            \A_files
```

Basically, **setA** gets two new folders, one for a copy of **A_files** and one to move  **B_files** into. In the end, nothing is removed from **setA** and the **setB** folder will be deleted.

Simple, but hard to explain.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide what you have tried so far.

Comment: How many folders? For only 3 folders just copy the files manually.

Comment: 200+ folders in each set

Comment: (1) I don't understand why you have both `setA\folderN\A_files` and `setA\folderN\A_files_folder\A_files`. (2) Break it down into simpler steps, and write scripts: (2a) Move `setB\folder1\B_files` into `setB\folder1\B_files_folder\B_files` (2b) do this for all `folderN` (2c) do the same for A (2d) move all the `B_files_folder` under `setB` into `setA`.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a lot of similar questions with appropriate answers here on SuperUser to figure out yourself how to start writing a script for this. Since you haven't mentioned what OS you're using I'll provide a Powershell solution for Windows.

Create the new subfolders in each folder in setA then loop through the files of setA and copy them to the appropriate `A_files_folder`.

```
Foreach ($dir in Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse .\setA) { New-Item -Path $dir.FullName -Name "A_files_folder" -ItemType "Directory"; New-Item -Path $dir.FullName -Name "B_files_folder" -ItemType "Directory"; } 
Foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse .\setA) { Copy-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $($file.DirectoryName + "\A_files_folder\") }
```

Dealing with the second part of the job we need to create the destination path using parts of the original file path but it's almost the same as the previous `Copy-Item` command. I would use this:

```
Foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse .\setB) { Move-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $(".\setA\" + $($file.DirectoryName.Split("\")[-1]) + "\B_files_folder\") }
```